# Rails + Devise custom views don't show nested fields well filled after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hy using `rails-3.2.13` with `devise-3.4.1`.
I have override the views:

```
rails g devise:views
```

And I have customized `new.html.erb` view:

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <%= f.fields_for :profile,resource.build_profile do |organization_form| %>
                <%= organization_form.text_field :name %>
                <%= organization_form.text_field :surname %>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.email_field :email %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>

  <% end %>
```

Everything works fine, except when there is a validation error. The form: `organization_form` isn't re-filled with the user input while the form `f` is well filled. So: `:name` and `:surname` are not re-filled after a validation error.

This is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :profile_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  ....
end
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<% resource.profile || resource.build_profile %>`, otherwise you won't get the passed values filled in on form failure.
So the `new.html.erb` now is like this:

```
<% resource.profile || resource.build_profile %>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <%= f.fields_for :profile do |organization_form| %>
                <%= organization_form.text_field :name %>
                <%= organization_form.text_field :surname %>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.email_field :email %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>

<% end %>
```